# Ruby (rails) conflicting class and modules names when nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module

I have a basic User model in app/models/user.rb. I also have a few services in lib. For example, I have lib/services/user/creation_service.rb. The following code generates an error:

```
# lib/services/user/creation_service.rb

module Services
  module User
    class CreationService
      ...
      def create_new_user
        # User.new below causes an error because it defaults to Services::User which is a module instead of User which is an ActiveRecord class
        User.new 
        ...
      end
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Is there any way to get User.new to refer to app/models/user.rb instead of the Services::User module in the code above?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `::User.new` would do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Use `::User.new` instead of `User.new`. The double colon basically tells ruby to look for the constant that does not have a parent.

So in this case `::User` will point to `User` which is a class instead of `Services::User` which is a module.